# Replace Timestamp placeholder in SQL string

Tags: java, sql

Here is the scenario:

I have a sample SQL query like:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE DATE = &Date
```

I wanted to replace this `&Date` at run time based on certain conditions. So I have a utility class which provides the actual `Timestamp`.

```
Timestamp timeStamp = Util.getTimeStamp("16102014 03:40:06")
```

Problem is while I am trying to replace it. If I replace it as a timeStamp.toString() [Not the right way to do it, just for testing I did], its getting replaced but my query became Invalid and I am getting SQL exception (`ORA-01861: literal does not match format string`).

What I wanted to achieve is I want to replace the place holder with timestamp value and execute the query.

**Constraints**

1. I can not use `PreparedStatement` set values as the query can be any arbitary query and I do not have prior information about the clause.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So, am I right in saying that a valid SQL query in this case is: `SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE DATE ='16102014 03:40:06'`? Or is it some other format. Seems that's what you need to determine?

Comment: @AlvinBunk Date format is the one mentioned in the query. But the `DATE ='16102014 03:40:06'` is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like this

```
SELECT ID, NAME 
  FROM MYTABLE 
 WHERE DATE = TO_TIMESTAMP(&Date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffffff')
```

Comment: @Alvin Yes,as I am doing this on Java. 

1. I got the &Date value as timestamp;
`Timestamp date =  Util.getTimeStamp("16102014 03:40:06");`
2. I formatted it like
`String formattedDate = "TO_TIMESTAMP('"+ date + "','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')";`
3. I formed the query 
`query = new StringBuffer(query.toString().replaceAll(&Date, formattedDate));`
4. Now I created i PreparedStatement and executed it.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are in "String" land, this is a "String" solution:

```
Timestamp timeStamp = Util.getTimeStamp("16102014 03:40:06")
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("''yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss''");
String formattedDate = format.format(timeStamp);
sql = sql.replace("&Date", formattedDate);
```

Note: The double `''` in the date format means produce a *single* quote in the output (a single quote is the delimiter for literal text in a date format).

Note also that because you're not using a driver, the character used to quote the text is database-dependant. This solution assumes that a single quote may be used for quoting a literal, but if your database requires a double quote `"`, the format should be `"\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\""`,

Comment: Thanks for the response. The above solution is generating this query

`SELECT ID, NAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE DATE = '2014-10-16 03:40:06'`.

But then we are back to the original problem. This query gives me 
`ORA-01861: literal does not match format string` exception.

Comment: What format do you need Som, or is this correct? Nice answer @Bohemian!

Comment: I am getting the timestamp as `2014-10-16 04:10:00.0` and I am using the `ddMMyyyy HH:mm:ss` format. 

The replacement is correct. My problem was executing the query.

Once again, thanks for the response.